# looking for manual for Nokky airconditioner

Tags: air-conditioning

Got an old air conditioner (Nokky) that displays an error. Because the manual is missing I've no idea what's wrong.

Searching the net does not give any results: the brand is not known. Does anyone knows the brand Nokky and can identify this model (and has some documentaion)?

[image: Nokky air conditioner]

Comment: Can you give any more information? The error code, how it behaves, what the model number is, pictures of the remote and outdoor unit?

Comment: Yes, can you give us model # information for the outdoor unit?

Comment: Many times (not always) you can find better info if you search on the model number, or even only part of the model number, as the factory may produce the same unit for several "brands" -  so if the model number is ABC123N perhaps the N is for Nokky, and you might find an ABC123B that was sold as Boojum but basically the same thing.